# Autosys JIL insert or update if exists

Tags: autosys

I'm trying to write an autosys JIL which creates the job if it doesn't exist but updates it otherwise. I would've sworn there was a command for that, like 'update_or_create' or something but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

there are three distinct commands: insert, update and delete _job. no "insert-or-update_job"

Answer (score 0):

You would best do this writing a Python script with something like SQLAlchemy/SQLACodeGen - then interrogate the AutoSys database to use the required verb prefix.